# InvalidTemplateEngineError in oscar

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-oscar

I am using django-oscar for my development.
I have created a new app as per my requirement

views.py

```
class MediaImportView(TemplateView):
  template_name = 'lookup/import_media_file.html'

  def get(self, request):
    ctx = {}
    return render(self.template_name, ctx, request, using=request)
```

getting the error as below.

> InvalidTemplateEngineError at /import_media_file

> Could not find config for '<WSGIRequest: GET '/import_media_file'>' in settings.TEMPLATES

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/), the `using` argument takes:

> The `NAME` of a template engine to use for loading the template.

Instead of passing the name of a template engine, you are passing a `request` object, hence the error. In addition, all your other arguments are wrong as well - the signature of this function is:

```
render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)
```

So the first argument needs to be a `request`, the second a template name, and the third the context. Something like this:

```
return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)
```